# Showing null pointer exception in setting the value in model class

Tags: java, android

Here goes my Activity class where there is a log which indicates that there is some value in selectedcategory String. But showing me exception when i am setting the value in my model class

## Activity Class

```
private ListView list;
    private MenuItem myActionMenuItem;
    private EditText myActionEditText;
    private TextView myActionTextView;
    private Spinner spinner;
    public Button live_event,save;
    private CategoryModel catModel;
    private String selectedCategory="";


    //private ArrayList <CategoryModel>categoryList;    

    //private static final String[]paths = {"All", "Favourites"};


    Map<Integer,Integer> categoryList;
    private ArrayList<String> categoryListPosition;
    private String selectCategoryID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(com.bioscope.R.layout.categorylist);
        save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

        categoryList=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

        RecieveCategoriesTask task = new RecieveCategoriesTask(this,"all");
        task.execute();


        save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for(int i=0;i<categoryList.size();i++)
                {
                //Log.i("array", categoryList.get(i).toString());
                if(categoryList.get(i)==1)
                {
                    selectedCategory+=categoryListPosition.get(i)+",";
                }

                }

                Log.i("array", selectedCategory);
                catModel.setSelectedCategory(selectedCategory);


                SendSelectedCategoryTask sendTask = new SendSelectedCategoryTask(
                        CategorySelectonActivity.this,catModel );
                sendTask.execute();
            }
        } );



    }

    public void showcateogryDataLoaded(ArrayList<CategoryModel> categoryList) {

            //this.categoryList = categoryList;


        this.categoryListPosition=new ArrayList<String>();

            int count=0;
            for(CategoryModel c:categoryList)
            {
                Log.v("title", c.getTitle());   

                this.categoryListPosition.add(c.getId());
                CategorySelectonActivity.this.categoryList.put(count, 0);
                count++;
            }


            CategorysListAdapter adapter=new CategorysListAdapter(this, categoryList);

            list=(ListView) findViewById(com.bioscope.R.id.listView1);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Toast.makeText(CategorySelectonActivity.this, "You Clicked an item ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //System.out.print("done");
                      //showEventInformaion(position);  



                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.select_checkbox);
                            if(cb.isChecked())
                            {
                             cb.setChecked(false);
                             CategorySelectonActivity.this.categoryList.put(position, 0);
                             for(int i=0;i<=CategorySelectonActivity.this.categoryList.size();i++)
                                {
                                    if(i==position)
                                    {
                                        CategorySelectonActivity.this.categoryList.put(i, 0);
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                             else 
                            {
                                cb.setChecked(true);
                                for(int i=0;i<=CategorySelectonActivity.this.categoryList.size();i++)
                                {
                                    if(i==position)
                                    {
                                        CategorySelectonActivity.this.categoryList.put(i, 1);
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                }
            });


    }



    public void visibleSaveButton()
    {

        save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


    public void selectedCategoryDataLoaded(String responseString) {
        Utility.showMessage(this, responseString + "");

    }
```

## Model Class

```
public class CategoryModel {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String selectedCategory;
    private byte[] icon;
    private boolean status;


    public byte[] getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void setIcon(byte[] icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getSelectedCategory() {
        return selectedCategory;
    }
    public void setSelectedCategory(String s) {
        this.selectedCategory = s;
    }
```

Then Later i get the value in my sendselectedcategorytask class

## SendSelectedCategoryTask Class

```
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    String responseString;
    String url;
    //String pageUrl = "createevent";
    CategorySelectonActivity appContext;
    private String userIdParameter="user_id=";
    CategoryModel catModel;

    public SendSelectedCategoryTask(CategorySelectonActivity c, CategoryModel model) {
        appContext = c;
        catModel = model;

        // url = Utility.baseUrl + pageUrl;
        url = " http://bioscopebd.com/mobileappand/userincategory?"+userIdParameter+"601514140076364784";

    }


    protected void onPreExecute() {

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(appContext);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setMessage("Saving Categories...");
        dialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    String filterResponseString(String r) {
        return r.replace("\r\n", "");
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpPost httppost;

        try {

            httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            MultipartEntityBuilder entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();




            entity.addPart("event_cat_id", new StringBody(catModel.getSelectedCategory()));


            httppost.setEntity(entity.build());

//          Log.v("Event Info",
//                  "Title: " + eventModel.getTitle() + "Description: "
//                          + eventModel.getDescription() + "Category: "
//                          + eventModel.getCategoryId() + "Publish Date: "
//                          + eventModel.getPublishDate() + "Start Date: "
//                          + eventModel.getStartDate() + "End Date: "
//                          + eventModel.getEndDate() + "Start Time: "
//                          + eventModel.getStartTime() + "End Time: "
//                          + eventModel.getEndTime() + "Logo: "
//                          + eventModel.getLogo() == null ? "NULL"
//                          : eventModel.getLogo().toString() + "Banner: "
//                                  + eventModel.getBanner() == null ? "NULL"
//                                  : eventModel.getBanner().toString());

            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
                responseString = filterResponseString(responseString);

                Log.v("RESPONSE ", "Response: " + responseString);
            } else {
                // Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();

                Utility.showMessage(appContext, "Cannot Connect To Internet");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Err", e.getMessage());
            // TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;


    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        dialog.dismiss();

        if (responseString != null) {


            appContext.selectedCategoryDataLoaded(responseString);

            // appContext.createEventDataLoaded();

        }

        super.onPostExecute(result);
```

// Do anything with response..
    }

## Logcat

```
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): Process: com.bioscope, PID: 1099
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.bioscope.main.CategorySelectonActivity$1.onClick(CategorySelectonActivity.java:89)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-15 11:19:00.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1099):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where's stack trace? Which line in stacktrace? Do you understand stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

In your activity class you defined CatModel as:

```
private CategoryModel catModel;
```

Which would initialize catModel with null. Then you don't initialize it in your Activity class and you try to use it like:

```
catModel.setSelectedCategory(selectedCategory);
```

Which is the reason for NullPointerException. If you initialize it or inject it (whatever your business need is), you should be able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
private CategoryModel catModel;
```

with

```
private CategoryModel catModel = new CategoryModel();
```